# Problema al Mostrar datos en ListView cogiendo datos de la Base Be Datos

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

Tengo un problema al mostrar los datos en un `listView`. El adaptador me da un error que pone `nullpointerexception` pero no se que pasa, no encuentro el error. Os adjunto el código del adaptador y de la clase de datos:

En la base de datos no da ningun error me da error al llamar al adapter desde el metodo `createlistview()` pero no me dice en que linea esta el error

Muchisimas gracias si me indicais el error o si me decir una manera para que esto funcione

Aquí tenéis todo el error que da android:

> 01-30 09:51:52.550
>   3541-3541/com.app.a2.studio.android.aprendiendo.appmanejarcuentas
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                                          Process: com.app.a2.studio.android.aprendiendo.appmanejarcuentas, PID:
>   3541
>                                                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.app.a2.studio.android.aprendiendo.appmanejarcuentas/com.app.a2.studio.android.aprendiendo.appmanejarcuentas.Screens.MainScreen}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>                                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                                                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                                              at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
>                                                                                                              at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.(Arrays.java:3826)
>                                                                                                              at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3813)
>                                                                                                              at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.(ArrayAdapter.java:139)
>                                                                                                              at
>   com.app.a2.studio.android.aprendiendo.appmanejarcuentas.DataBase.FolderAdapter.(FolderAdapter.java:0)
>                                                                                                              at
>   com.app.a2.studio.android.aprendiendo.appmanejarcuentas.Screens.MainScreen.createListView(MainScreen.java:86)
>                                                                                                              at
>   com.app.a2.studio.android.aprendiendo.appmanejarcuentas.Screens.MainScreen.onCreate(MainScreen.java:50)
>                                                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
>                                                                                                              at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>                                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>                                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>                                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>                                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

La clase **FolderDatos** es así:

```
public class FolderDatos {

    public int icon;
    public String title;
    public int ID;
    public int numberUsers;

    public FolderDatos(int icon, String title, int numberUsers, int ID){
        this.icon = icon;
        this.title = title;
        this.numberUsers = numberUsers;
        this.ID = ID;
    }
}
```

Clase del **adaptador**:

```
package com.app.a2.studio.android.aprendiendo.appmanejarcuentas.DataBase;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.app.a2.studio.android.aprendiendo.appmanejarcuentas.R;


public class FolderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FolderDatos> {

    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceID;
    private FolderDatos[] folderDatos = null;

    public FolderAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceID, FolderDatos[] folderDatos){
        super(context, layoutResourceID, folderDatos);

        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceID = layoutResourceID;
        this.folderDatos = folderDatos;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View row = convertView;
        FolderDatosHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null){
            LayoutInflater folderInflate = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();

            row = folderInflate.inflate(layoutResourceID, parent, false);

            holder = new FolderDatosHolder();
            holder.groupIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.iv_lvd1_GroupImage);
            holder.groupName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_lvd1_GroupTitle);
            holder.numberUsers = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_lvd1_numberUsers);
            holder.ID = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_lvd1_ID);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }

        else {
            holder = (FolderDatosHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        FolderDatos folderDatos = this.folderDatos[position];

        holder.groupIcon.setImageResource(folderDatos.icon);
        holder.groupName.setText(folderDatos.title);
        holder.numberUsers.setText(String.valueOf(folderDatos.numberUsers));
        holder.ID.setText(String.valueOf(folderDatos.ID));

        return (row);
    }

    private static class FolderDatosHolder{
        ImageView groupIcon;
        TextView groupName;
        TextView numberUsers;
        TextView ID;
    }
}
```

La **base de datos**:

```
package com.app.a2.studio.android.aprendiendo.appmanejarcuentas.DataBase;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class BaseDeDatos extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DB_NAME = "AppCuentas.db";

    public static final String TABLE_FOLDERS = "Folders";

    public static final String TF_COLOM_ID = "_ID";
    public static final String TF_COLOM_NUMBER_USERS = "NumberUsers";
    public static final String TF_COLOM_NAME = "Nombre";

    public static final String TABLE_USUARIOS = "Usuarios";
    public static final String TU_COLOM_PRIMARY_ID = "_ID";
    public static final String TU_COLOM_FOLDER = "Folder";
    public static final String TU_COLOM_NAME = "Nombre";
    public static final String TU_COLOM_DESCRIPTION = "Descripcion";
    public static final String TU_COLOM_PAGOS = "Pagos";


    public BaseDeDatos(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FOLDERS
                + " (" + TF_COLOM_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + TF_COLOM_NAME + " TEXT, "
                + TF_COLOM_NUMBER_USERS + " INTEGER) ");

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USUARIOS
                + " (" + TU_COLOM_PRIMARY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + TU_COLOM_FOLDER + " TEXT, "
                + TU_COLOM_NAME + " TEXT, "
                + TU_COLOM_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, "
                + TU_COLOM_PAGOS + " INTEGER) ");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST" + TABLE_FOLDERS);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST" + TABLE_USUARIOS);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

    }

    public boolean addData(String name, int numberUsers){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues valuesFolders = new ContentValues();

        valuesFolders.put(TF_COLOM_NAME, name);
        valuesFolders.put(TF_COLOM_NUMBER_USERS, numberUsers);

        long resultFolders = db.insert(TABLE_FOLDERS, null, valuesFolders);

        if(resultFolders == -1){
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean addData(int folder, String name, String description, float pagos){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues valuesUsuarios = new ContentValues();

        valuesUsuarios.put(TU_COLOM_FOLDER, folder);
        valuesUsuarios.put(TU_COLOM_NAME, name);
        valuesUsuarios.put(TU_COLOM_DESCRIPTION, description);
        valuesUsuarios.put(TU_COLOM_PAGOS, pagos);

        long resultUsuarios = db.insert(TABLE_USUARIOS, null, valuesUsuarios);

        if(resultUsuarios == -1){
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Cursor getAllFoldersData(){
        String folderColoms[] = {TF_COLOM_ID, TF_COLOM_NAME, TF_COLOM_NUMBER_USERS};
        Cursor c = this.getReadableDatabase().query(TABLE_FOLDERS, folderColoms, null, null, null, null, null);
        return c;
    }

    public Integer deleteFolder(String folderID){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Integer usuers = db.delete(TABLE_USUARIOS, "Folder = ?", new String[] { folderID });
        Integer folders = db.delete(TABLE_FOLDERS, "ID = ?", new String[] { folderID});

        if(usuers > 0){
            if(folders > 0){
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }

    }
}
```

y el **listView**:

```
private void createListView() {
        db = new BaseDeDatos(this);
        Cursor cursor = db.getAllFoldersData();
        FolderDatos[] folderDatos = null;
        FolderAdapter folderAdapter = null;
        int ID, numberUsers;
        String nombre;
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                ID = cursor.getInt(0);
                numberUsers = cursor.getInt(2);
                nombre = cursor.getString(1);
                folderDatos = new FolderDatos[]{new FolderDatos(R.drawable.ic_group, nombre, numberUsers, ID)};
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        if(folderDatos == null){
            folderAdapter = new FolderAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_design1, null);
        }
        else {
            folderAdapter = new FolderAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_design1, folderDatos);
        }
        listview.setAdapter(folderAdapter);
        listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                TextView tv_title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_lvd1_GroupTitle);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tv_title.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Cuelga la traza completa para que podamos ver la línea en que da el error.

Comment: ¿Podrías subir la traza del error para que sea más fácil identificar que es lo que está pasando? Otra cosa más, para futuras preguntas intenta no hacer capturas del código, sino pegar tu código, ya que con las capturas no podemos copiar el código para intentar reproducir el error. Saludos.

Comment: @Joacer lo siento soy nuevo en el foto...

Comment: @ProRiderZ115 tranquilo, sólo quería darte unos consejos para futuras preguntas, para que a la gente le sea más fácil ayudarte!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me haría falta ver tu Activity completa para validarlo , por el número de línea, pero tiene toda la pinta de fallar en

```
folderAdapter = new FolderAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_design1, null);
```

El new FolderAdapter hace un

```
Arrays.asList(objects)
```

Y este da el error que tienes si la colección es nula.
Cambia el código a

```
folderAdapter = new FolderAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_design1, new FolderDatos[0]);
```

Así lo inicializas con una colección vacía.

Para recoger la información de BD:

```
private void createListView() {
    db = new BaseDeDatos(this);
    Cursor cursor = db.getAllFoldersData();
    List<FolderDatos> folderDatos = new ArrayList<>();
    FolderAdapter folderAdapter = null;
    int ID, numberUsers;
    String nombre;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            ID = cursor.getInt(0);
            numberUsers = cursor.getInt(2);
            nombre = cursor.getString(1);
            folderDatos.add(new FolderDatos(R.drawable.ic_group, nombre, numberUsers, ID)};
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    folderAdapter = new FolderAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_design1, folderDatos.toArray(new FolderDatos[folderDatos.size()]));
    listview.setAdapter(folderAdapter);
    listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            TextView tv_title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_lvd1_GroupTitle);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tv_title.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Como ves, en cada iteración del bucle guardo un nuevo objeto FolderDatos, y más tarde uso esa colección para cargar el Adapter.
Con un Array no podría hacerlo ya que no se puede saber de antemano el número de posiciones con que crear este array.

Comment: Vale ahora la app ya se me abre aunque sea y no crashea pero el list view no se me actualiza, es decir, no se lee bien la base de daos o no se añaden bien los datos al vector y no entiendo por que si tu lo supieras
Solo he cambiado de codigo lo que tu me has dicho. Si necesitas mas parte de mi codigo pidemela @pablo

Comment: Comprueba que la variable folderDatos es distinta de null y, de ser así, si tiene valores dentro. Creo que no estás tratando bien la manera en que recuperas los datos, concretamente el bucle do/while, y cada iteración del bucle borras el contenido (por el new new FolderDatos[]).

Comment: Y como hago para arreglar ese bucle? @pablo