# Problema al mostrar Datos en ListView Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

Para mostrar los datos desde la base de datos uso un bucle do-while que recorre toda la tabla pero al añadir los datos al vector no se que pasa que no se añaden bien y en el `listView` solo se muestra un grupo y si añado otro no se muestra y si borro el que se esta mostrando no se borra del `listView` hasta que reinicio la app.
No da ningún error ni nada. Si meto los datos manualmente en el vector si que se muestran en el `listView`

Os dejo el código:

Base de datos:

```
package com.app.a2.studio.android.aprendiendo.appmanejarcuentas.DataBase;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class BaseDeDatos extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DB_NAME = "AppCuentas.db";

    public static final String TABLE_FOLDERS = "Folders";

    public static final String TF_COLOM_ID = "_ID";
    public static final String TF_COLOM_NUMBER_USERS = "NumberUsers";
    public static final String TF_COLOM_NAME = "Nombre";

    public static final String TABLE_USUARIOS = "Usuarios";
    public static final String TU_COLOM_PRIMARY_ID = "_ID";
    public static final String TU_COLOM_FOLDER = "Folder";
    public static final String TU_COLOM_NAME = "Nombre";
    public static final String TU_COLOM_DESCRIPTION = "Descripcion";
    public static final String TU_COLOM_PAGOS = "Pagos";


    public BaseDeDatos(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FOLDERS
                + " (" + TF_COLOM_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + TF_COLOM_NAME + " TEXT, "
                + TF_COLOM_NUMBER_USERS + " INTEGER) ");

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USUARIOS
                + " (" + TU_COLOM_PRIMARY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + TU_COLOM_FOLDER + " TEXT, "
                + TU_COLOM_NAME + " TEXT, "
                + TU_COLOM_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, "
                + TU_COLOM_PAGOS + " INTEGER) ");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST" + TABLE_FOLDERS);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST" + TABLE_USUARIOS);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

    }

    public boolean addData(String name, int numberUsers){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues valuesFolders = new ContentValues();

        valuesFolders.put(TF_COLOM_NAME, name);
        valuesFolders.put(TF_COLOM_NUMBER_USERS, numberUsers);

        long resultFolders = db.insert(TABLE_FOLDERS, null, valuesFolders);

        if(resultFolders == -1){
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean addData(int folder, String name, String description, float pagos){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues valuesUsuarios = new ContentValues();

        valuesUsuarios.put(TU_COLOM_FOLDER, folder);
        valuesUsuarios.put(TU_COLOM_NAME, name);
        valuesUsuarios.put(TU_COLOM_DESCRIPTION, description);
        valuesUsuarios.put(TU_COLOM_PAGOS, pagos);

        long resultUsuarios = db.insert(TABLE_USUARIOS, null, valuesUsuarios);

        if(resultUsuarios == -1){
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Cursor getAllFoldersData(){
        String folderColoms[] = {TF_COLOM_ID, TF_COLOM_NAME, TF_COLOM_NUMBER_USERS};
        Cursor c = this.getReadableDatabase().query(TABLE_FOLDERS, folderColoms, null, null, null, null, null);
        return c;
    }

    public Integer deleteFolder(String folderID){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        //Integer usuers = db.delete(TABLE_USUARIOS, "Folder = ?", new String[] { folderID });
        Integer folders = db.delete(TABLE_FOLDERS, "_ID = ?", new String[] { folderID });

        if(folders > 0){
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
        /*
        if(usuers > 0){
            if(folders > 0){
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
        */

    }
}
```

El adaptador:

```
package com.app.a2.studio.android.aprendiendo.appmanejarcuentas.DataBase;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.app.a2.studio.android.aprendiendo.appmanejarcuentas.R;


public class FolderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FolderDatos> {

    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceID;
    private FolderDatos[] folderDatos = null;

    public FolderAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceID, FolderDatos[] folderDatos){
        super(context, layoutResourceID, folderDatos);

        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceID = layoutResourceID;
        this.folderDatos = folderDatos;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View row = convertView;
        FolderDatosHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null){
            LayoutInflater folderInflate = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();

            row = folderInflate.inflate(layoutResourceID, parent, false);

            holder = new FolderDatosHolder();
            holder.groupIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.iv_lvd1_GroupImage);
            holder.groupName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_lvd1_GroupTitle);
            holder.numberUsers = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_lvd1_numberUsers);
            holder.ID = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_lvd1_ID);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }

        else {
            holder = (FolderDatosHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        FolderDatos folderDatos = this.folderDatos[position];

        holder.groupIcon.setImageResource(folderDatos.icon);
        holder.groupName.setText(folderDatos.title);
        holder.numberUsers.setText("Miembros: " + String.valueOf(folderDatos.numberUsers));
        holder.ID.setText(String.valueOf(folderDatos.ID));

        return (row);
    }

    private static class FolderDatosHolder{
        ImageView groupIcon;
        TextView groupName;
        TextView numberUsers;
        TextView ID;
    }
}
```

La clase FolderDatos:

```
package com.app.a2.studio.android.aprendiendo.appmanejarcuentas.DataBase;



public class FolderDatos {

    public int icon;
    public String title;
    public int ID;
    public int numberUsers;

    public FolderDatos(int icon, String title, int numberUsers, int ID){
        this.icon = icon;
        this.title = title;
        this.numberUsers = numberUsers;
        this.ID = ID;
    }
}
```

El main activity completo:

```
     package com.app.a2.studio.android.aprendiendo.appmanejarcuentas.Screens;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.app.a2.studio.android.aprendiendo.appmanejarcuentas.DataBase.BaseDeDatos;
import com.app.a2.studio.android.aprendiendo.appmanejarcuentas.DataBase.FolderAdapter;
import com.app.a2.studio.android.aprendiendo.appmanejarcuentas.DataBase.FolderDatos;
import com.app.a2.studio.android.aprendiendo.appmanejarcuentas.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BaseDeDatos db;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private String bitMapImage;
    private ListView listview;

    private String APP_DIRECTORY = "MajearCuentasApp/";
    private String MEDIA_DIRECTORY = APP_DIRECTORY + "media";
    private String TEMPORAL_PICTURE_NAME = "temporalPicture.png";

    private final int PHOTO_CODE = 100;
    private final int SELECT_PICTURE = 200;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

        variableCastings();
        createListView();
        createToolBar();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_toolbar, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void variableCastings(){
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tb_ams_ToolbarMain);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_ams_ListView);
    }

    private void createListView() {
        db = new BaseDeDatos(this);
        Cursor cursor = db.getAllFoldersData();
        FolderDatos[] folderDatos = new FolderDatos[cursor.getCount()];
        FolderAdapter folderAdapter;

        int ID, numberUsers, counter = 0;
        String nombre;

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                ID = cursor.getInt(0);
                numberUsers = cursor.getInt(2);
                nombre = cursor.getString(1);

                folderDatos[counter] = new FolderDatos(R.drawable.ic_group, nombre, numberUsers, ID);
                counter++;
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

            folderAdapter = new FolderAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_design1, folderDatos);

        folderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listview.setAdapter(folderAdapter);

        listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                TextView tv_ID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_lvd1_ID);
                createOptionsAlertDialog(tv_ID.getText().toString());
                return true;
            }
        });
    }


    private void createOptionsAlertDialog(final String ID){
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainScreen.this);
        final AlertDialog dialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.options_menu_items, null);

        dialog.setView(v);

        dialog.show();

        Button btnEliminar = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_omi_btnDelete);
        Button bntEditar = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_omi_btnEditar);
        Button bntCancel = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_omi_btnCancel);

        btnEliminar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Integer isDeleted = db.deleteFolder(ID);

                if(isDeleted > 0){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Borrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error al borrar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createToolBar(){
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("AppWIP");
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_toolbar);
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case (R.id.item_addFolder):
                        createFolderAletrDialog();
                        return true;

                    case (R.id.item_addIndividual):

                        return true;

                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void createFolderAletrDialog(){
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainScreen.this);
        final AlertDialog dialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_folder_design, null);

        dialog.setView(v);

        dialog.show();

        final EditText etGroupName = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.et_cfd_FolderName);
        final ImageView ivGroupIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_cfd_GroupImage);
        Button btnAddImage = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_cfd_AddPhoto);
        Button btnCrear = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_cfd_ADCrear);
        Button btnCancel = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_cfd_ADCancel);

        /*
        btnAddImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent galeryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                galeryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galeryIntent.createChooser(galeryIntent, "Sececiona Imagen"), SELECT_PICTURE);
            }
        });
        */

        btnCrear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (etGroupName.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No puedes crear un grupo sin nombre", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    addDataToFolderTable(etGroupName.getText().toString(), 0);
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }
        });

        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
    }

    private void addDataToFolderTable(String name, int numberUsers) {
        boolean isInserted = db.addData(name, numberUsers);
        if(isInserted){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Guardado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error al guardad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode){
            case (SELECT_PICTURE):
                if(requestCode == RESULT_OK){
                    // Tengo la imagen
                    Uri path = data.getData();
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ha llegado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: estás declarando tu `folderDatos` con un tamaño de `0`. Nunca va a existir mas datos mas allá de lo q hayas declarado. Deberías usar un `ArrayList< FolderDatos>` para tu `folderDatos`

Comment: Ya preguntó, y fue respondido, por ese problema.

Comment: @marlonpya tienes razón : FolderDatos[] folderDatos = new FolderDatos[0]; en realidad esta dimensionado para un elemento en el array.

Comment: Podrías actualizar tu código con los cambios que haz realizado para ver en que parte sigue estando la falla?

Comment: @Bourne ahi lo tienes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es que se añadan los datos tienes dos detalles que impiden esta tarea, primeramente el array `FolderDatos[]` no esta dimensionado correctamente, únicamente aceptara un registro:

```
 FolderDatos[] folderDatos = new FolderDatos[0];
```

puedes dimesionarlo con la cantidad de elementos contenidos en el cursor:

```
 FolderDatos[] folderDatos = new FolderDatos[cursor.getCount()];
```

en segundo lugar, no debes crear otra instancia del array `FolderDatos[]` en cada bucle,

```
  folderDatos = new FolderDatos[]{new FolderDatos(R.drawable.ic_group, nombre, numberUsers, ID)};
```

debes agregar cada nuevo elemento al array:

```
 int counter = 0;
 if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                ID = cursor.getInt(0);
                numberUsers = cursor.getInt(2);
                nombre = cursor.getString(1);

              // folderDatos = new FolderDatos[]{new FolderDatos(R.drawable.ic_group, nombre, numberUsers, ID)};
              folderDatos[counter] = new FolderDatos(R.drawable.ic_group, nombre, numberUsers, ID);
            counter++;
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
```

con esto al final obtendrás un array `folderDatos[]` conteniendo todos los datos no solo uno.

Para actualizar los datos del Adapter visualmente realizalo mediante [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()):

```
folderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Sigue funcionando como antes, no se actualiza el listView hasta que cierro y abro la app nose que estara mal.. @Jorgesys
Si lo necesitas te puedo pasar la clase MainScreen entera a ver si ves tu el fallo..

Comment: Me parece que simplemente es como y cuando llamas el método createListView(), sería bueno agregaras más info para determinar el problema que comentas. @ProRiderZ115

Comment: Ahi tienes todo el codigo java que tiene hasta ahora mi app

Comment: @ProRiderZ115 la pregunta es, como deseas que realice la carga y actualización de datos?, actualmente solo tienes la llamada en onCreat() por esa razón al iniciar, (y probablemente al rotar la aplicación) se cargan los datos. Mediante que acción o botón deseas actualizar?

Comment: Me dices que debo llamar al metodo createListView() cada vez que añado, borro o actualizo algo?

Comment: Si deseas ver la actualización en el Adapter cada vez que realizas operaciones "CRUD", tu obtienes los datos en el cursor, este cursor se obtiene dentro del método createListView(), por lo tanto la respuesta es si.

Comment: vale ya esta solucionado es que tenia un error de concepto grande

Answer (score 0):

Después de actualizar la lista dentro del adapter, debes llamar a notifyDataSetChanged() para actualizar el listado.

```
listview.setAdapter(folderAdapter);
folderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

La manera en que preparas los datos tampoco es correcta. El por qué está mal este código ya te lo respondí [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46706/problema-al-mostrar-datos-en-listview-cogiendo-datos-de-la-base-be-datos).

Comment: Muchas gracias pero me sigue pasando lo mismo...@pablo

Comment: Perdon no lo vi, ahora ya si que se me ven mas de un solo item en la lista pero no se actualiza hasta que no cierro y abro la app y he puesto lo que me dijistes de folderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); @pablo